# Calling child method to parent class and getting error related to no attribute

Tags: python, class, inheritance, superclass

Following is a sample code. I am trying to implement similar in an extensive code.

I have performed enough research about it but I could not find any specific explanation related to my problem.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.e = self.gete()
    def typing(self):
        return self.d
    def gete(self):
        return self.d +1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        super().__init__(a,b)
        self.c = c
        self.d = self.getd()

    def getd(self):
        return self.c+1

kk = B(1,2,3)
print(kk.typing())
print(kk.e)
```

My expected result is 5. But instead, it is raising an error.

`"AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute'"` But in fact it has a line
`"self.d = self.getd()"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `B.__init__()`, you call `super().__init__()` before you assign `self.d`. Therefore, *at the time you call* `A.__init__()`, there is no `d` attribute on the object, so `A.gete()` fails.

To fix this, you can call `super().__init__()` *after* setting `self.d` in `B.__init__()`.